# Logging Failed Model data in ELMAH

Tags: c#, elmah

How to log something like `List<CustomModel>` in ELMAH?

Tried the following however it doesn't work:

> Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("Error
>   Model "  + CustomModel));

Answer (score 2):

ELMAH doesn't support custom properties like other frameworks (log4net, Serilog etc.). If you want to store the content of the list, you can use something like [json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize the list to a JSON string before sending it to ELMAH:

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("Error Model " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CustomModel);));
```